# I need to make backup from partitioned table (Hive)

Tags: sql, hive, partitioning

I need to make backup data from partitioned table which has over 500 partitions.
My table has partitioning by date_part like "date_part = 20221101" or "date_part = 20221102" etc.
I need to take 30 partitions from 20221101 to 20221130 and make copy to another new backup-table.

If I do something like this:

```
create table <backup_table> as
select * from <data_table> where date_part between 20221101 and 20221130
```

at the output I get non-partitioned <backup_table> and idk is it good way or not but i guess partitioned <backup_table> will be more better.

If I try to do:

```
create table <bacup_table> like <data_table>;
insert overwrite table <backup_table> partition (`date_part`)
select * from <data_table> where date_part between 20221101 and 20221130;
```

At the output I get error like need to specify partition columns...

If I go another way:

```
create table <bacup_table> like <data_table>;
insert overwrite table <backup_table> partition (`date_part`)
select field1, field2...,
date_part
from <data_table> where date_part between 20221101 and 20221130;
```

I get another errors like "error running query" or  "...nonstrick mode..." or something else.
I've tried a lot of hive settings but it still not work :(

Thats why I need your help to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable dynamic partition and copy the data.

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
SET hive.mapred.mode = nonstrict;
```

Comment: Good to hear. Please accept the answer :)

Comment: sure) and the last question: how can I drop partitions in <data-table> or replace on new data?

Comment: alter table table_name drop partition (parition_name). Before that check your table is managed or exteranl table. If it is managed table, u will loose your data. be careful while dealing with drop partition. Once done. , execute msck repair table_name. just for metadata refresh

Comment: thank you for your help! It's very useful for me and someone else I guess :) good luck